# Sharing ASP.NET logged in user data between two sites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I need to integrate two ASP.NET sites user-wise. I have a Web Pages ASP.NET 4 site that allows users to login. It has a custom user provider. Now I have written an ASP.NET MVC3 site that needs to work seamlessly with the Web Pages site and to only allow certain actions to be called by certain users that come from Web Pages site's user provider. As a final resort, MVC site can access user datastore of the Web Pages site.

P.S. I can configure ASP.NET MVC site to be in a sub-folder of a Web Pages site in IIS if this is necessary.

Comment: do they share the same ***"domain"***? it will work if you navigate between ***sub-domains*** - given the proper configuration ...

Comment: Yes, they will share the same domain. Can you go ahead an post general info about "proper configuration" as an info? This might as well be actually what I need to know =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup `FormsAuthentication` to be used across multiple sub-domains, configure the following:

Specify the domain of the Authentication cookie without a particular sub-domain - allows the browser to access the Authentication ticket from any sub-domain:

```
<!-- ... -->
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/Index" domain="authtest.com"> ... </forms>
    <!-- ... -->
</authentication>
<!-- ... -->
```

Make sure the separate applications use the *same* machine keys so they can encrypt/decrypt the authentication ticket properly:

```
<!-- ... -->
<system.web>    
    <machineKey validationKey=" ... 3D26FD5F940C2FD0AF8065F29A"
            decryptionKey=" ... 940CD33EBCE5065F2F2334D"
            validation="SHA1"  decryption="AES" />
    <!-- ... -->
</system.web>
<!-- ... -->
```

Everything else is standard ASP.Net Authentication details/configurations.

Comment: Xander, would this approach require both site to use the same membership provider with the same configuration to access user data in the database?

Comment: theoretically no, as long as the sites use the same primary domain and the cookie is set properly.